# regex to match an optional dot

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

Given a filename structured like:

```
<type>.<unit>.<snip>.<hostname>.<number>.text
```

where `snip` is optional text that may contain extra dots
but `type`, `unit`, `hostname`, etc. are fixed.

Some examples would be:

```
interfaces.InterfacesIxLacp.router.001.text
policies.RoutingPoliciesIx.BOGONS-EXT-V6-in.router.002.text
```

I would like to match the following filenames:
text

The problem is `<dot><snip><dot>` that the 2nd  is optional depending on the existence of `<snip>`.
In the example above `snip` is equal to `BOGONS-EXT-V6-in`.

What is a generic regex that can take into account both cases ?
I am using `glob` from Python standard library to get the filenames: (this "works")

```
glob.glob('policies.RoutingPoliciesIx.*router.*.text')
glob.glob('interfaces.InterfacesIxLacp.*router.*.text')
```

But, what I would like to is to have a `.` (dot) in the regex just before `router`. As what is after the `.` truly signifies the router hostname.

I have tried this, unsuccessfully:

```
glob.glob('policies.RoutingPoliciesIx.*(\.)?router.*.text')
```

Could you please help and advise how the regex should look like in order to address the above problem ?

Comment: `glob` is *not* a regex.

Comment: See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/714503/regular-expressions-vs-filename-globbing

Comment: For example `*.txt` is not a valid regex, but it is a valid "glob" pattern.

Comment: with `fnmatch` then ?

Comment: if that name parts condition is fixed, you can just use `first_pass = str.rsplit('.', maxplit=3)` to separate the `<hostname>`, `<number>`, `text` parts from the first parts in the filename, including `<snip>` if it exists. then it's a matter of splitting & joining `first_pass[0]` to separate `<snip>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `re.match` or `re.search` instead.

Answer (score 0):

if that name parts condition is fixed, you can just use string parsing

```
filename1 = 'policies.RoutingPoliciesIx.BOGONS-EXT-V6-in.router.002.text'
filename2 = 'interfaces.InterfacesIxLacp.router.001.text'

first1 = filename.split('.')[:2]
last1 = filename.rsplit('.', maxsplit=3)[1:]

first2 = filename2.split('.')[:2]
last2 = filename2.rsplit('.', maxsplit=3)[1:]

>>>> first1
['policies', 'RoutingPoliciesIx']
>>>> last1
['router', '002', 'text']
>>>> filename1 = '.'.join(first) + '.'.join(last)
>>>> filename1
'policies.RoutingPoliciesIxrouter.router.002.text'

>>>> filename2 = '.'.join(first) + '.'.join(last)
>>>> filename2
'interfaces.InterfacesIxLacprouter.router.001.text'
```